# Getting this error file.absolute.existsSync() when trying to getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() of the app and add to it the File that is selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add get the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory of the device and trying to add to it the image(File) that the user is selected but i'm getting an error.

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery, requestFullMetadata: false);

Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images');

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

String filePath = '$appDocDir${image!.path}';

File file = File(filePath);

ref.putFile(file);
```

// the output of the print(filepath)

flutter: Directory: '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/88B9CD81-EF63-4ED1-9608-42C38D364BED/Documents'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/88B9CD81-EF63-4ED1-9608-42C38D364BED/tmp/image_picker_CEF1D50E-0B60-4257-9BBC-A82A9A684314-592-0000001041AF8CDF.jpg

Comment: what the error can you please add that to question

Comment: @AhmadRaza thanks for response, this is the error that i'm getting file.absolute.existsSync()